# How can I disable a service been monitor on the prometheus-operator stack

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator

We have deployed the `prometheus-operator` stack on `AWS` `EKS`

By default it monitors all services deployed.

Is it possible to configure the `prometheus-operator` stack to by default monitor all services with the exceptions of services "`foo`" and "`bar`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use service monitor resource to limit what to be monitored:
take a look at [documentation](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/1acb34abbcbe33a30a05d8b31cc4c37d545e10ce/Documentation/user-guides/running-exporters.md#generic-servicemonitor-example)

you can remove services from monitoring by excluding them from selector or namespace selector in serviceMonitor specification.

as an example:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: k8s-apps-http
  labels:
    k8s-apps: http
spec:
  jobLabel: k8s-app
  selector:
    matchExpressions:
    - {key: foo, operator: NotIn} <---
    - {key: bar, operator: NotIn} <---
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
    - kube-system
    - monitoring
  endpoints:
  - port: http-metrics
    interval: 15s
```